# Python, Read a file as number

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I tried to make an economy minigame in my discord.py bot.
I save the balance of people in different text files (bot is for me and 3 other friends)

Now if it reads the files and needs to add up two numbers as a variable it says :
*discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not '_io.TextIOWrapper'*

I want it to read the file as a number.

This is my code:

```
async def beg(ctx):
    file = open(ctx.author.name, 'w')
    number = ("10","25","69","75","100")
    begmoney = (random.choice(number))
    balance = open(ctx.author.name, "r")
    newmoney = begmoney + int(balance)
    await ctx.send(newmoney)
    file.write(newmoney)
    await ctx.send("you got " + begmoney )
    await ctx.send("your balance now is: " + file.read())
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You have to actually read the file first, then cast it. *PS: You should use a context manager, it's better practice.*

Comment: `balance` is the file object obtained from `open` call and hence cannot be converted to `int`

Comment: It whould be easier to use a dictionary in this scope, I did a command similar to yours, and I did it encoding a dictionary into a single .json file

Answer (score 0):

From the code what I got is you are trying to get a random number and add it to the balance amount in the file and write the new amount back to it.
Is this what you should be doing:

```
async def beg(ctx):
    number = ("10","25","69","75","100")
    begmoney = (random.choice(number))
    balance = 0
    with open(ctx.author.name, 'r') as file:
        balance = file.read().strip()
    with open(ctx.author.name, 'w') as file:
        newmoney = begmoney + int(balance)
        await ctx.send(f'{newmoney}')
        file.write(f'{newmoney}')
        await ctx.send(f"you got {begmoney}"  )
        await ctx.send("your balance now is: " + file.read())
```

Comment: Thanks for the respond, now i get another error: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: Not sure where are you getting this error. However have edited a code bit in string concatenation part. Can you try the new code.?

Comment: it still gives the same error

Comment: I think arguments to be passed should of type string. Have changed the code at all places of send.

Comment: It gives again the same error

Comment: This will require more information on exactly at which line is the error seen, etc.

Comment: Does this help you? :
  File "E:\Python\Hyper Bot II\hyper.py", line 129, in beg
    newmoney = begmoney + int(balance)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''